# Python List Manipulation for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tabulate

I have a List im trying to split and manipulate :

```
t = ['total percentage,Successful Divert 2935 95.9%,Operational Defect 67 2.2%,MHE Defect 59 1.9%,Load Balancing Defect 1 0.0%']
```

Im having a hard time figuring out the best way to manipulate for pandas.

Desired output:

```
t = [['Successful Divert','2935','95.9%'],'[Operational Defect','67','2.2%'],['MHE Defect','59','1.9%'],['Load Balancing Defect','1','0.0%']]
```

Pandas output:

| Metrics | Total | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Successful Divert | 2935 | 95.5% |
| Operational Defect | 67 | 2.2% |
| MHE Defect | 59 | 1.9% |
| Load Balancing Defect | 1 | 0.0% |

Comment: Have you tried `split` for the list?

Comment: What happened to "total percentage" at the first part of the raw list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should works for you

```py
t = [
    "total percentage,Successful Divert 2935 95.9%,Operational Defect 67 2.2%,MHE Defect 59 1.9%,Load Balancing Defect 1 0.0%"
]
t2 = [x.split(" ") for x in t[0].split(",")[1:]]
t3 = [(" ".join(x[:-2]), x[-2], x[-1]) for x in t2]
pd.DataFrame(t3, columns=["Metrics", "Total", "Percentage"])
```

Output:

[image: Output:]

Comment: You are the man .. thanks . I really need to try harder haha

Comment: Or: `pd.DataFrame((el.rsplit(maxsplit=2) for el in t[0].partition(',')[2].split(',')), columns=["Metrics", "Total", "Percentage"])`